# How to combine and transpose this dataset using GAS when this is not a tabular dataset yet?

Tags: google-apps-script

How can this be achieved given the format displyed below?
[image]

I see that there are suggestions like [this](https://gist.github.com/femto113/1784503), but it doesn't quite cover the format below.

I barely started it, because I really am not sure where to go from here:

```
let dates = ["","01/01/2021","02/01/2021","03/01/2021","04/01/2021","05/01/2021","06/01/2021"]
```

```
let data = [[1,"Item A","",10,15,9,8,10,15],[2,"Item B","",20,25,35,20,5,15],[3,"Item C","",10,25,24,26,26,1]]
```

```
function savedata() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const itemsSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Items');
  const dataRng = itemsSheet.getRange(4, 1, 3, itemsSheet.getLastColumn());
  let dates = itemsSheet.getRange(2, 3, 1, itemsSheet.getLastColumn() - 2).getValues().flat();
  dates = dates.map(e => e !='' ? Utilities.formatDate(new Date(e), Session.getTimeZone(), "MM/dd/yyyy") : '')
  const data = dataRng.getValues();
}
```

Appreciate any direction!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your sample values of `dates` and `data` are used, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  // These values are from your question.
  let dates = ["", "01/01/2021", "02/01/2021", "03/01/2021", "04/01/2021", "05/01/2021", "06/01/2021"];
  let data = [[1, "Item A", "", 10, 15, 9, 8, 10, 15], [2, "Item B", "", 20, 25, 35, 20, 5, 15], [3, "Item C", "", 10, 25, 24, 26, 26, 1]];

  // Create an array for putting to the sheet.
  const [, ...d] = dates;
  const [variance, item, , ...values] = data[0].map((_, c) => data.map(r => r[c]));
  const res = d.flatMap((e, i) => variance.map((f, j) => [e, f, item[j], values[i][j]]));

 // The values are put to "Sheet1".
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, res.length, res[0].length).setValues(res);
}
```

- When this script is run, using your provided sample values, your expected values are put to "Sheet1".
- I think that in this case, if you want to use the date object of the date, you can directly use the retrieved values by `getValues`.

#### Reference:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: @onit Thank you for the quick reply and for testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Comment: What if more cols are to be considered besides ```variance``` and ```item```? I'm trying to add these like this, but not working: ```const [, ...d] = dates;
  Logger.log('Response: ' + JSON.stringify(data[0].map((_, c) => data.map(r => r[c]))));
  const [id, fullName, position, workType, rate, hoursWeek, dateHired, terminationDate, ...values] = data[0].map((_, c) => data.map(r => r[c]));
  const res = d.flatMap((e, i) => id.map((f, j) => [e, f, fullName[j], position[j], workType[j], rate[j], hoursWeek[j], dateHired[j], terminationDate[j], values[i][j]]));``` Would it be a new question?

Comment: @onit About your new question of `What if more cols are to be considered besides variance and item?`, I would like to support you. But the issue of replying is new issue, and that is different from your question. So can you post it as new question? Because when your initial question is changed by comment, other users who see your question are confused. By posting it as new question, users including me can think of it. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve your new question?

Comment: @onit By the way, unfortunately, from `not working`, I cannot understand your situation. So, when you post it as a new question, can you include more information for helping to understand your new question?

Comment: Thank you! I've tried adding more columns to it on the top of the solution you gave above and it works. I'm trying to get this right with my real situation. I'll try a bit more before posting another question! Thank you!

Comment: @onit Thank you for replying. I'm glad your new issue was also resolved.

Comment: Can't thank you enough for this!